# how to get Tabcontrol's Tab focus in WPF

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I am New in WPF

I have one form on which I put one datagrid as well as there is one "Add New" button to add new item in grid

so is there any way to know about tab lost focus when click on Add new button and again get focus on tab control ? Lostfocus event of tab control does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the control in question is getting focus, and that you are subscribing to the correct event? Have a look at the specs for LostFocus and the order of events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx

Also posting some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [TabControl.SelectionChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.selectionchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
void TabControl_TabSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is TabControl)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```